# Ubuntu 22.04 endless searching for devices but nothing found bluetooth

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

I am new to Ubuntu. My Bluetooth does an endless search for devices but nothing could be found. The output of dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm' gives:

```
    1.647441] usb 3-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio
    [    2.071071] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
    [    2.093567] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
    [    2.093593] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
    [    2.093595] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [    2.093599] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [    2.093602] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [    2.093608] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [    2.120772] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
    [    2.120777] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000b, hci ver 000b
    [    2.120780] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
    [    2.668171] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x0101001F
    [    2.668770] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.16 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 3
    [    2.668774] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
    [    3.480761] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [    3.480764] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [    3.480768] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [   24.816567] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
    [   24.816573] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
    [   24.816577] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
    [  573.711422] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
    [  648.522053] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000007e15b852 failed to resubmit (2)
    [  664.207897] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
    [  664.207904] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000b, hci ver 000b
    [  664.207907] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
    [ 1375.388305] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
    [ 1375.388313] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000b, hci ver 000b
    [ 1375.388315] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
    [ 1603.940851] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
    [ 1605.024424] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
    [ 1605.024429] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000b, hci ver 000b
    [ 1605.024430] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
    [ 2948.816244] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
    [ 2949.900149] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
    [ 2949.900155] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000b, hci ver 000b
    [ 2949.900157] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
    [ 3209.141303] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
    [ 3210.205750] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
    [ 3210.205754] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000b, hci ver 000b
    [ 3210.205756] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
    [ 4705.099710] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel comman
```

Maybe it is this line:

```
    [  648.522053] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000007e15b852 failed to resubmit (2)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a kernel issue which happens if your kernel is >= 5.9, you can use `uname -r` to check your kernel version.
Some related threads: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=259954

As a user of MX master 3S and ubuntu22.04, I use logitech bolt receiver and [solaar](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar) to customize it for now.

Hope this would help.